# How to send a message in messenger using javascript? (Google Chrome Console)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sendmessage, messenger

Is there a way to send a message in messenger using google chrome console?

For example :

```
sendMessage("My Message");
```

Comment: Simple answer is no.

Comment: But how does messenger send the message after you hit enter or press the button "Send message"?